# перенос элементов flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

появилась проблема не получается ни как сделать вот такие row и columns, можете помочь?

Нужно через flex сделать этот пример показанный на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы бы показали кодом, что пробовали делать, а не картинку. Тут это не очень приветствуется и вместо ответа скорее набросают минусы за вопрос. И почему именно `flex`? Такие задачи гораздо удобней решаются с помощью `grid`. Вот, к примеру, [таким](https://jsfiddle.net/yjthegL6/) или [таким](https://jsfiddle.net/yjthegL6/1/) образом.

Comment: @Akbaraliev, пожоже на flex masonry. Но, делать это на flex - такое себе. Слишком геморно... там и с порядком проблем хватает и со всем остальным. Рассмотрите, по возможности, grid

Answer (score 0):

Выполнил эту задачу на CSS Grid

```css
    body {
        background-color: rgb(44, 46, 87);
    }

    .parent {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 16px);
        width: 100%;
    }

    .box {
        border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    .div1 {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 2;
        background-color: rgb(151, 191, 83);
    }

    .div2 {
        grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
        background-color: rgb(151, 191, 83);
    }

    .div3 {
        grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
        background-color: rgb(182, 46, 55);
    }

    .div4 {
        grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
        background-color: rgb(220, 177, 76);
    }

    .div5 {
        grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
        background-color: rgb(182, 46, 55);
    }

    .div6 {
        grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
        background-color: rgb(182, 46, 55);
    }

    .div7 {
        grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
        background-color: rgb(220, 177, 76);
    }

    .div8 {
        grid-area: 2 / 4 / 4 / 5;
        background-color: rgb(151, 191, 83);
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1 box"></div>
    <div class="div2 box"></div>
    <div class="div3 box"></div>
    <div class="div4 box"></div>
    <div class="div5 box"></div>
    <div class="div6 box"></div>
    <div class="div7 box"></div>
    <div class="div8 box"></div>
</div>
```